# Error when install app from android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi I have made a simple app and when I want to test it I connect my phone 1 to computer by USB cable and the app run  very good then I share the app to my other phone 2 and other phones from phone 1 and when I try to install it on the other phones it says can't be installed.
Is the issue from phones or from the app I wored if I publish it on Google play
It's doesn't work pls help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "then I share the app to my other phone 2"? How did you share the app to another phone?

Comment: I share it from my phone to another and it didn't work

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I share from my phone to another and it didn't work

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I share it using share app

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I mean I send the app files to other phone

Comment: What share app? What is the exact name of the app? What exact steps did you follow to do this? Show screenshots to illustrate these steps.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice How can i send screen shot. I use phone app

Comment: To send screenshots, you can [edit] your question and click on the Image button in the editor toolbar.

Comment: I have a guess about the problem. See my answer below and check out the link I give tot he documentation that will help you fix the problem.

Comment: Have you before installed this app via cable on phone 2?

Comment: @OlgaKonoreva no

Comment: Hmm, in this case it could have been mismatching of different debug keystores. Anyway, I'd advice you: 1) Try to install on phone 2 via usb and ensure that it's not a device specific problem. 2) Use one keystore (debug or release, but common!) - you could add debug keystore into the project and sign APK using Build -> Generate Signing Apk...

Comment: @OlgaKonoreva I run it on phone 2 via cable and it's work fine

Comment: @OlgaKonoreva and I go to build > generate signed bundle / app > I selected Android App Bundle and I created a new one then I signed and I selected release and finish and and the problem still so what's the wrong

Comment: please, ensure that you don't have any instances of this app on the device before trying to install

Comment: https://www.digitbin.com/app-not-installed-fix-error/ this could help you

Answer (score 1):

The error appears because Android Studio signs your apk with the debug.key by default. Documentation is [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode). When you sign it with the release key as Google Play requires, the problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Installing an app on your phone requires that the APK file is signed with a certificate. When you install an app to your phone with Android Studio, it generates a keystore with a certificate and signs your app. This generated keystore is insecure and can only be used for development. Most likely your other phone is not allowing you to install the app signed with this insecure key.

To fix this, you need to generate a certificate to sign your APK with. For instructions how to do this, read [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)